# Error - Undefined index: user while migrating Laravel 8

Tags: php, oracle, migration, laravel-8

When I run migration in Laravel 8 with Oracle 12 (remote connection) after some successful migrations I get the following error:

```
Migrating: 2017_11_26_013050_add_user_role_relationship

   ErrorException 

  Undefined index: user

  at vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractOracleDriver.php:81
     77▕     public function getDatabase(Connection $conn)
     78▕     {
     79▕         $params = $conn->getParams();
     80▕ 
  ➜  81▕         return $params['user'];
     82▕     }
     83▕ 
     84▕     /**
     85▕      * {@inheritdoc}

      +36 vendor frames 
  37  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

In the logs:

```
[2021-09-03 16:31:15] local.ERROR: Undefined index: user {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: user at /xxx/xxx/xxx/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractOracleDriver.php:81)
[stacktrace]
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have had a hell of a time trying to migrate Laravel that is accessing Oracle (11g in my case). I ended up not moving the app using it to Lv8. I'm gonna wait for the community devs to have a chance to catch up.